# Web Sql Syntax error is detected on Android-4.4 but not below 4.4 version

Tags: android, cordova, web-sql

We are developing an app using cordova 3.5.0.The websql database has been used to store the results. We are getting the data from the google app engine sever
by using goole end points which is in the form of JSON like below along with the sql statements.

```
"dropLocalEntity": "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Tenant",
 "createLocalEntityQuery": "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tenant (companyName TEXT, tenantId TEXT, branchId REAL)",
 "insertLocalEntityQuery": "INSERT INTO Tenant (companyName, tenantId, branchId) VALUES ('a11','a11:aswath.satrasala@gmail.com',5649391675244544),('SARAH FOODS PVT LTD','SARAH FOODS PVT LTD:audit.kgrco@gmail.com',2299139),('AYEE EDU TECH PRIVATE LTD','AYEE EDU TECH PRIVATE LTD:cakrishnaraj.in@gmail.com',2001),('NCOPL','NCOPL:alok@natureconnect.in',7001),('CP Real Estate Pvt ltd','CP Real Estate Pvt ltd:26april1973@gmail.com',5001),('Elite ProCon Solutions','Elite ProCon Solutions:ratna@eliteprojects.com',6001),('Team Works Technologies','Team Works Technologies:rashmi.kgrco@gmail.com',5001),('DFCPL','DFCPL:sameer.wazir@dfcplonline.com',94001),('PASUPATI ADVISORY PVT LTD','PASUPATI ADVISORY PVT LTD:anilroongta01@gmail.com',6001),('DEF','DEF:DEF786ABC@gmail.com',5001),('Kudos Site','ENGINEERS ASSOCIATES:info@engineersassociates.co.in',241003),('ENGINEERS ASSOCIATES','ENGINEERS ASSOCIATES:info@engineersassociates.co.in',5865619656278016),('Pepper Foods','Pepper Foods:puneet@pepperfoods.com',2002),('Viswalam','Viswalam:viswabooks@gmail.com',49104),('Vishnu Chakara Cement','Vishnu Chakara Cement:vishnuchakaracement@gmail.com',5144752345317376)",
 "fetchLocalEntityQuery": "SELECT * FROM Tenant",
 "kind": "listtenantendpoint#resourcesItem",
 "etag": "\"BFH8YzudjMA4FocHBq774qlnFyw/O1ihN9-TWxWWwYKaN99yGSokHUU\""
```

We are getting the above data at mobile side(client) and forms the tables and rendering properly to disply the data. With all the things the my app is working good.
Here the problem is that i am able to display my data on the android mobile(android-4.2) but not able to rendered the data on mobile(android-4.4).
 The following is displaying on the android-4.4 mobile.

> could not prepare statement(1 near ",": syntax error)

My database opening statement is:

```
var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
```

Comment: your insert statement is not correct. You are inserting multiple records in a single insert statement. i.e `insert into tenant (column name...) VALUES( record values..1) ,(record values..2) ,( record values..3)`. You can insert only **ONE** record at a time in an insert statement with the VALUES option. i.e `insert into tenant (column name...) VALUES( record values..1)`

Comment: but this was working fine with android-4.2 mobile

Comment: Theoretically it should not have worked on 4.2. Anyway you can test  your code with a single insert to confirm that the error is bcos of multiple values.

Comment: It is quite possible that the sqlite shipped with the device you are testing on does not support the particular syntax.

Comment: It is okay but the web sql is not dependes on device, it is on the default browser of a particular device.

Answer (score 0):

As a alternative you can use the UNION clause for inserting multiple values.

Use a UNION:

```
INSERT INTO `mytable` 
 (`col1`, `col2`) 
SELECT 1, 'aaa'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'bbb'
```